# I cannot convert a String to Integer in in Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, string

I was trying to make a little program where you can input a number and it would be displayed on the screen.

The problem is, whenever I type in a number it gives me either a `NumberFormatException` or another Exception... and I don't know what to do, I tried doing it in a method with `try{}` and `catch{}` where I said `int i = Integer.parseInt(String);` and I also tried to do that directly but none of it worked.

```
//in "Window" class

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        else if(e.getSource() == submit) {
            Lines.drawPointLine(null);
        }
    }
```

```
//in "Lines" class

    public static void drawPointLine(Graphics g) {
        if(pointPosX == 0) {
            int i;
            g.drawLine(30, 490, 60, convertPointPos(i = Integer.parseInt(window.enterpoint.getText())));
        }
    }

    public static int convertPointPos(int point) {
        int s = (int) (point * 0.46);
        int retpoint = 490 - s;
        System.out.println(retpoint);
        return retpoint;
    }
```

Here is the code where I tried to convert it directly but it still gives me an Exception and I don't know what to do...

Comment: You need to understand what you write. Your `actionPerformed`method starts `else if...`. Don't you think there is a missing part?

Comment: What exact Exception do you get? The `NumberFormatException` tells you what the input was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only guessing.

Maybe you have to `trim()` whitespaces from the beginning and end of a string before parsing?

```
Integer.parseInt(window.enterpoint.getText().trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are trying to parse a float number (eg. 1.1) the `Integer.parseInt(String s)` can only parse a String that contains only numbers AND a minus sign (\u002D) or a plus sign (\u002B).

If you want to parse a float number you may want to use `Double.parseDouble(String s)`.

Comment: No, I am trying to add a number between 0 and 1000 in form of an int